# What sense can be made out of TIME_WAIT, CLOSE_WAIT, ESTABLISHED

Tags: performance, analytics, connections

Using netstat command, I got the number of couple of TCP states of connections. 
But for running websites, how to make meaningful connections between these numbers and the bottleneck/performance of the website?

```
TIME_WAIT 2363
CLOSE_WAIT 5
FIN_WAIT1 32
FIN_WAIT2 161
ESTABLISHED 643
SYN_RECV 28
CLOSING 1
LAST_ACK 26
```

Please save the manual-kind links and share some practical knowledge, thanks!

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully this will help, [detailed explanation here](https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/1552/~/netstat-explained):-

- **CLOSED** Indicates that the server has received an ACK signal (to
  acknowledge receipt of a packet) from the client and the connection
  is closed.
- **CLOSE_WAIT** Indicates that the server has received the first FIN
  signal (to acknowledge there is no more data to be sent) from the
  client and the connection is in the process of closing.
- **ESTABLISHED** Indicates that the server received the SYN signal
  (synchronize, this signal is only sent in the first packet) from the
  client and the session is established.
- **FIN_WAIT_1** Indicates that the connection is still active but not
  currently being used.
- **FIN_WAIT_2** Indicates that the client just received acknowledgement of the first FIN signal from the server.
- **LAST_ACK** Indicates that the server is in the process of sending it's own FIN signal.
- **LISTENING** Indicates that the server is ready to accept a connection.
- **SYN_RECEIVED** Indicates that the server just received a SYN signal from the client.
- **SYN_SEND** Indicates that this connection is open and active.
- **TIME_WAIT** Indicates that the client recognises the connection as active, but not currently being used.

Comment: So 2363 (TIME_WAIT) means 2363 online users at current time? ( They are more or less visiting the website?)

Comment: @Jusfeel Well, that's the number of unused connections - given that a http connection is accessing one resource that doesn't really mean users.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles, Isn't this question off-topic here?